# different variable increment on different call

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I am having a list that contains a button for each item in the list.
For each button click, I want a variable should be incremented through the JavaScript function i.e. common function for all the buttons in the list.

```
<button onclick="GetIncrements(resource_id)">
```

For this I have following javascript:

```
function GetIncrement(id){
if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
        if (localStorage.clickcount) {
            localStorage.clickcount = Number(localStorage.clickcount)+1;
        } else {
            localStorage.clickcount = 1;
        }
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You have clicked the button " + localStorage.clickcount + " time(s).";
}
```

Every time I click on the different buttons in the list, the same variable get updated. But I want to get different variable get incremented based on the `resource_id`.

I want separate counter for each button in the same function.

I can not make different functions for different click because list is dynamic.

If there is a way that we can generate a dynamic variable in the function based on `resource_id` we are getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is something like this:

```
 function GetIncrement(id){            
         if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
            var storageKey = "clickcount" + id;
            if (localStorage[storageKey]) {
                localStorage[storageKey] = Number(localStorage[storageKey])+1;
            } else {
                localStorage[storageKey] = 1;
            }
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You have clicked the button " + localStorage[storageKey] + " time(s).";
          }
      }
```